# Query to divide string between a specified string and a number in two rows

Tags: sql-server, string, split

I would like to know how to run a query to divide or separate **by the word and** this strings:

- 3 semester hours in elementary accounting and 3 in general business (12/68)(12/68)
- 3 semester hours in materials management and 3 in business management and organization

Into this:

- 3 semester hours in elementary accounting
- 3 in general business (12/68)(12/68)
- 3 semester hours in materials management
- 3 in business management and organization

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that it is not going to be more than two sets per row, you could use a customized set of substring, left and charindex functions to solve this. Taking the two cases from your question as a sample:

```
;with cte as 
(select 1 as id,'3 semester hours in materials management and 3 in business management and organization' as text
UNION
select 2 as id,'3 semester hours in elementary accounting and 3 in general business (12/68)(12/68)' as text)

select id,  
       left(replace(text,'management and organization','management & organization'),
            charindex(' and',replace(text,'management and organization','management & organization'),1)-1) as text
from cte

UNION ALL

select id,  
       SUBSTRING(replace(text,'management and organization','management & organization'),
            charindex(' and',replace(text,'management and organization','management & organization'),1)+5,100) as text
from cte
```

I have used 'and' as a delimiter here. So, you will have to replace all other 'and' occurrences with something else (I have used & in the example). Hope this helps.